# How to use Python Subprocess to drop a database schema?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, subprocess, database-schema

I want to drop the database (PostgreSQL) schema using python subprocess.

I have come up with this:

```
subprocess.call(['psql', '-U', DB_USER, DB_NAME, 'drop schema', SCHEMA_NAME, 'cascade'])
```

but it gave me this error:
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "drop schema" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "demo1" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "cascade" ignored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for psql states that the command is passed via the -c option as a single value. The following uses the -d option as the psql doesn't permit options after positional arguments as to avoid reordering the options.

```
subprocess.call(['psql', '-U', DB_USER, '-d', DB_NAME, 
    '-c', ' '.join(['drop schema', SCHEMA_NAME, 'cascade'])])
```

Comment: It worked, thank you. But I didn't use '-d' and it still worked.